# Angularjs - adding time to $interval

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a session with a timeout in my `AngularJS` application, and I want to be able to add time to the session while its running.

For this I'm using `$interval`, however I don't seem to be able to change values once they are in the interval, is this true or am I doing it wrong?

```
    var sessionCountdown,
        session,
        sessionTime;
        timeleft = 0;

    function start() {
        if(session === undefined){
            if(Account.get().isLoggedIn){
                setTimeleft();
            } else {
                $interval.cancel(session);
            }
        }
    }

    function setTimeleft(time){
        if(time === undefined){
            Config.get()
                .then(function(config){
                    sessionTime = config.sessionTime;
                    if(sessionTime !== undefined){
                        timeLeft = sessionTime * 60000;
                        timeout();
                    }
                });
        } else {
            timeLeft = time;
            timeout();
        }
    }

    function timeout(){
        if(session === undefined){
            session = $interval(function(){
                if(timeLeft === undefined){
                    $interval.cancel(session);
                }
                console.info('time : ', timeLeft);
                timeLeft -= 1;
                if(timeLeft <= 0){
                    showModal();
                    $interval.cancel(session);
                    session = undefined;
                }
            }, 1000);     //  60.000 milliseconds = 1 minute.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, at time function 'start()' fired Account.get().isLoggedIn is defined?

Comment: Use `$timeout` for timeouts. You can chain extra time to them.

Comment: @DanDuh: `isLoggedIn` is defined ^^
@georgeawg: Would it be possible for you to give an example on how to add/reset time on a $timeout?